# Не срабатывает broadcastreceiver на получение смс при закрытом приложении

Tags: android, sms

уважаемые форумчане. Пишу простейшее приложение для получения смс. Идея такая: нужно контролировать температуру с датчика, подключенного к расбери. По превышению определенной уставки на смартфон должно приходить соответствующее смс. Всё как положено-имею активити, класс SMSReceiver с широковещательным приемником broadcastreceiver и манифест приложения.
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sms;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.os.Environment;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

private Button get_temp;
private Button set_ustavka;
private EditText ustavka;
private TextView temp_vel;
private TextView status;
private ImageView img;
private ImageView img_off;
String ust;

boolean bound = false;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    get_temp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_temp);
    set_ustavka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_ustavka);
    ustavka = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ustavka);
    temp_vel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_vel);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img_off = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_off);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            
        } else {

            checkAndRequestPermissions();
        }
    }

}

SMSReceiver mReceiver = new SMSReceiver();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}

public boolean checkPermission() {
    int smsPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

    return smsPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int send_sms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    int receive_sms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (send_sms != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    }
    if (receive_sms != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),0);
    SmsManager sms= SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null, message,pi,null);
}
```

}

SMSReceiver.java

```
package com.example.sms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
String smsMessageStr;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
            byte[] pdu = (byte[])pdus[i];
            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
            smsMessageStr = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}

И собственно Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.sms">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/wdc_dll_6"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver
        android:name=".SMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Проблема в том, что при открытом или свернутом активити приемник работает-смс приходит и вываливается тост с текстом сообщения, но при закрытом приложении приемник вообще не срабатывает. Все разрешения привел в манифесте. Там же указал сам приемник с интент фильтром...В интернете везде аналогичные примеры и якобы у всех все работает. Вобщем никак не могу разобраться, что я делаю не так. Может проблема с разрешениями, но открытое приложение и в фоне работает...

Comment: А как вы "закрываете" приложение? Если через ForceStop то оно никак после этого не сможет работать.

Comment: я закрываю как обычно через телефон, не использую для этого стронние программы

Comment: Что значит как обычно? Сторонние программы для принудительной остановки не нужны. Может быть у вас прошивка девайса так работает. Попробуйте на эмуляторе запустить. И смахнуть из списка приложений а потом как то съэмулировать интент на смс. Может быть получится такое сделать

Comment: ну я как раз из списка приложений и закрываю свайпом

Comment: может приоритет побольше выставить?